# MySQL search for item with all tags

Tags: mysql, tagging

I'm working on a search engine for an online library, but I'm kind of stuck here. When searching for tags, OR searches (ie books with "tag1" OR "tag2") work fine, but the AND searches are giving me some trouble.

The tables (and their columns) I use for this are:

```
books  | book_id, other_info
tagmap | map_id, book_id, tag_id
tags   | tag_id, tag_text
```

Since a bunch of other search options can be en/disabled by the user, the query is generated by PHP. When searching for books with the tags "tag1" AND "tag2", the following query is generated:

```
SELECT DISTINCT b.book_id, b.other_info
FROM books b, tagmap tm, tags t
WHERE b.book_id = "NA"
OR ( (t.tag_text IN ("tag1", "tag2"))
      AND tm.tag_id = t.tag_id
      AND b.book_id = tm.book_id )
HAVING COUNT(tm.book_id)=2
```

The WHERE line (which doesn't give any results) is there so that additional parameters may be strung to the query more easily. I know this can be handled a lot nicer, but for now that doesn't matter.

When doing an OR search (same query but without the HAVING COUNT line), it returns the two books in the database that have either of those tags, but when searching for the one book in the database that has BOTH tags, it returns nothing.

What's wrong with the query? Is this not the/a way to do it? What am I overlooking?

Thanks!

EDIT: As per request, the data from each table relating to the book that should be returned:

```
books table:
book_id     110

tagmap table:
book_id     110    110
tag_id      15     16

tags table:
tag_id      15     16
tag_text    tag1   tag2
```

**SOLUTION**: All I had to do was include

```
GROUP BY b.book_id
```

before the HAVING COUNT line. Simple as that. The answer provided by taz is also worth looking into, especially if you're aiming for optimising your search queries.

Comment: Can you post the data from the tables that should be displaying?

Comment: Also, you should use inner joins instead of a comma-separated list of table names. It is very easy to make mistakes and sometimes to compute a large cartesian product with the list syntax!

Comment: The only thing that will be displaying is other information about the book, which I summarised in the other_info column. Or do you mean all data involved in running the query?

Comment: I meant can you post the actual data from the rows that you are attempting to display, because it would help to see the data that is used when running this query. It is not necessary to see thousands of other rows, but a few would be helpful. I'm trying to see if multiple rows that are returned from the query without the HAVING clause have the same book_id, because the having clause means there needs to be 2 rows returned with the same book ID

Comment: Added. That is indeed the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comma separated list of tables in your FROM clause functions like an inner join, so your query is selecting all of the rows in the tagmaps table and the tags table that have the same tag ID, and of those rows, all of the rows from the books table and the tagmaps table that have the same book ID. The HAVING clause then requires that two rows be returned from that result set with the same book ID. There can only be one row in the books table with any given book ID (assuming book ID is the primary key of the books table), so this condition is never met.

What you want is a join without the books table. You are looking for the same book ID appearing twice in the results of the OR clauses (I believe), so you don't want to join the books table with those results because that will ensure you can never have the same book ID in the results more than once.

Edit: conceptually, you are essentially combining two different things. You are looking for tags and tagmaps for the same book, and you are also getting the book info from each of those books. So you are actually pulling duplicate other_info data for every instance of the same book ID in the tagmaps table, and then using the distinct clause to reduce that duplicate data down to one row, because all you want is the book ID and other_info. I would consider using two queries or a subquery to do this. There may be other [better] ways as well. I'd have to play around with it to figure it out.

For starters, try

```
SELECT DISTINCT tm.book_id, b.other_info
FROM tagmap tm inner join tags t
    on tm.tag_id = t.tag_id
  left join books b
    on tm.book_id = b.book_id
HAVING count(tm.book_id) = 2
```

Comment: I think I understand. However, after removing the "books b" join, replacing every b.book_id with tm.book_id, and removing the last AND clause, I still do not get a result. Weird thing though: I tried with two different tags that also belong to an item, and it worked fine for that one, even with my incorrect query. Other items/tags still don't work though, what's up with that?

Comment: I found a solution to my problem (which I'll add to the question in a minute), but I will definitely look into queries similar to the one you suggested. Guess there are multiple roads that lead to Rome, eh. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @Fang No problem. Sorry I didn't have time to get back to you sooner. The `GROUP BY` should also work for your purpose, although you still might be pulling more data than you need. Regarding still getting no results, I'd recommend making sure you are explicitly joining tables with a JOIN clause instead of using a comma list and checking that you're using the correct ID fields. Based on the info you gave & without actually testing the SQL, I think it should work. You pull all tagmaps & tags that have the same tagID, and then you pull all books that have the same bookID as each tagID.

Comment: Yeah, I already used another approach. Replaced everything after OR with `book_id IN (subquery)`, where subquery is a query generated using PHP, INNER JOINing for each tag, as with the recommended query here: http://bit.ly/JjxPGo . I guess that's what you were aiming for too.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT book_id FROM tagmap JOIN tags ON (tag_id) WHERE tag_text = "tag1"
INTERSECT
SELECT book_id FROM tagmap JOIN tags ON (tag_id) WHERE tag_text = "tag2"
```

Wrap this whole thing as a sub query to select other book info you need:

```
SELECT book_id, other_info FROM books WHERE book_id IN
(
   ...
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, look like I did complex solution for mysql database (should be fine for any other). So, database structure is this:

```
source (id)
tag(id)
tags(source, tag)
```

Cover this requirements:

- Fetch sources with ANY of selected tags OR with ALL selected tags
- Fetch sources which did not contain excluded tags

Query here:

```
 SELECT source.id 
 FROM source
 -- optional join, if you need to include sources with tags:
 LEFT JOIN tags tags_include ON source.id = tags_include.source
 -- optional join, if you need to exclude sources with tags
 LEFT JOIN tags tags_exclude ON source.id = tags_exclude.source
      -- here list of excluded tags
      and tags_exclude.tag in(1)
 WHERE
    -- optional condition, tags which you need to include
    tags_include.tag IN (2, 3)
    -- optional condition, which will exlcude sources with excluded tags
    and tags_exclude.source is null
 GROUP BY source.id
 -- optional having, in case when you include tags with "AND" strategy
 -- count should be equal to count of selected tags
 -- if you fetch sources with "OR" strategy, ignore this having
 HAVING count(1) >= 2
 ORDER BY source.id DESC
 LIMIT 0, 50;
```

So, this query will fetch 50 newest sources, which have tag with id 2 and 3, and which have no tag with 1.